# django m2m_changed not working

Tags: python, django, signals, models

i have simple code, bug not working!
after added a tag to content not called `tag_update_count_use`!

models .py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    count_use = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('count use'), default=0)

    def update_count_use(self, delta):
        self.count_use += delta
        self.save(update_fields=['count_use'])

class Content(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True, verbose_name=_('tags'))
```

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Content.tags)
def tag_update_count_use(sender, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    return kwargs
```

__init__.py

```
default_app_config = 'content.apps.ContentConfig'
```

apps.py

```
class ContentConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'content'
    verbose_name = _('content')

    def ready(self):
        import content.signals
```

according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed i changed code to :

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Content.tags.though)
```

but i receive this error:

```
AttributeError: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'though'
```

Comment: You've missed out the `r` in `through`.

Comment: Thank you
I'm a little tired!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed out the `r` in `through`. Try:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Content.tags.through)
```